# convert the code to get list with 2nd braces

Tags: java

I have below piece of code where inputs are dynamic. Here I have taken 2 inputs but there are much more inputs.

I am iterating this method() in a loop.
In the first iteration [name=ram, empNo=1] is added.
In next iteration further details are added and output is::[name=ram, empNo=1, name=shyam, empNo=2]
public class Main2 {
static  List list=new ArrayList<>();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> list1=add();
    
    
    list.addAll(list1);
    System.out.println(list);
}

private static List<String> add() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> list2=new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add("name=ram");
    list2.add("empNo=1");
    return list2;
}
```

}

I am getting output as below: [name=ram, empNo=1, name=shyam, empNo=2] after 2nd iteration.
But I need final output as :: [{name=ram, empNo=1}, {name=shyam, empNo=2}]

can anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not telling the method to do any of it. The list2 is simply a List of Strings, so how should it know, that after every second item it is supposed to add a "}, {"?

What you would have to do is define a class for the employee with the fields name and empNo, define the toString()-method such, that it returns `"name=" + this.name + ", empNo=" + this.empNo` and add those items to the list.
Afterwards you could use a StringJoiner to create your wanted output like this:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoinr("}, {", "[{", "}]");
list1.forEach(employee -> joiner.add(employee.toString()));
System.out.println(joiner);
```